# How to get python to work with an interactive shell enviroment?

Tags: python, bash

I am currently trying to get python to work interactively. Lets say for instance I have an executable that runs and asks for a name. This executable does not take any arguments, just inputs. How would I go about writing a python script that will put in all possible names in my word list.

I have not tried much because I cant find very many resources on this topic.
Here is what the program looks like

```
bash@laptop:$ ./names.elf
What is your name? (enter the name here)
```

```
import os

with open('name.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        os.system('./names.elf ')
        print('=' * 50)
```

For my code above I expect it to start the executable file and print the line it is currently reading.

Comment: Use the subprocess library instead of `os.system()` and write the data to the `stdin` of the running process.

Comment: give the absolute path of the script like os.system("/home/zz/names.elf")